# Nesting Stack Navigator with Drawer Navigator

Tags: navigation-drawer, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am trying to have stack navigation along with drawer navigation. Basically I want the drawer to be in only one scene all time. I have tried to do so but nothing occurs. I am not being able to understand what I am doing wrong.

**P.S:** I am new to react-native.

**ConversationListScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    TouchableNativeFeedback,
    Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import styles from './styles';

export default class ConversationListScreen extends Component
{
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Hola',
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => Alert.alert('Hi!', 'I am a hamburger.')}>
                <View style={styles.toolBackground}>
                    <Icon name="menu" style={ styles.menuIcon }/>
                </View>
            </TouchableNativeFeedback>
        ),
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => Alert.alert('Hi!', 'What you want to search?')}>
                <View style={styles.toolBackground}>
                    <Icon name="search" style={ styles.searchIcon }/>
                </View>
            </TouchableNativeFeedback>
        )
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Drawer.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';

export default class SideNav extends Component
{
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>My first Drawer</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig.js**

```
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ConversationListScreen from './ConversationListScreen';
import Drawer from './Drawer';
import ChatScreen from './ChatScreen';

export const SideNav = DrawerNavigator({
    Drawer: { screen: Drawer},
});

export const Hola = StackNavigator({
    ConversationList: { screen: ConversationListScreen },
    Drawer: { screen: SideNav },
    Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and what I ended up doing was using [this drawer component](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer) and wrapping it around the component you want to access it with. For example if you want to access it only from ConversationListScreen you export it as `<Drawer><ConversationListScreen></Drawer>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't use drawer navigator in stack navigator as a scene. you should import SideNav in the component you want to use and try to render it as a component

Comment: If I import it as a component then how to show and hide the side bar? Can you show me a snippet?

Comment: you are right. I forgot this. look at my working solution I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround. We have two screens in HomeScreenNavigator which is a stackNavigator. in firstScreen we have a link to secondScreen. in secondScreen we have drawerNavigator which has a screen named ComponentWidthDrawer. this component has a button to open drawer. I tested it and it's working.

```
class FirstComponent extends Component{
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
this.props.navigation.navigate("SecondScreen")}>
          <Text>Go to Second Component</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
class ComponentWidthDrawer extends Component{
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
          <Text>Open Menu</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const SecondComponent = DrawerNavigator({
  Drawer: {
    screen: ComponentWidthDrawer,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Videos'
    },
  }
})

const HomeScreenNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    FirstScreen : {
      screen: FirstComponent,
      navigationOptions:{
        header: false
      }
    },
    SecondScreen: {
      screen: SecondComponent,
      navigationOptions:{
        header: false
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: My RouteConfig is in a file named `RouteConfig.js` and I would prefer to keep all routes in one place. My scenario is that the `ConversationListScreen` is the default home screen. There I want to have a hamburger menu which will open and close the drawer, but that menu should not be on any other page.

Comment: you can configure header in navigationOptions so displaying or hiding the hamburger icon shouldn't stop you from using this. and the first nested screen can be conversationlist which takes you there by default